# Compare strings with different spaces and potentially null characters

Tags: javascript, encoding, removing-whitespace

I'm currently making a wikipedia scraper for a project I'm doing. The problem is that my code sometimes produces bugs when trying to compare strings. If I have strings that look identical, they sometimes are still registered as different. For example:

```
var elementText = $("selector").text();
console.log(elementText); // "abc def"
console.log(elementText === "abc def"); // false
```

It seems that Wikipedia uses some weird characters that my code detects and doesn't like. I have tried:

```
function replaceBadSpaces(string) {
    return decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(string).replace("/%C2%A0/g", "%20"));
}
```

and using `elementText.replace(/\s+/g, '')`, and neither seem to work. How can I completely get rid of these characters so that strings that are intuitively equal actually do match as equal?

Note: I have also tested my code with `==`, and it does seem to fix the issue; however, in the interest of avoiding future bugs I'd like to avoid using this fix.

Comment: Also did you know you can [download the entire database for free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download)?

Comment: @Liam I did not. I'll definitely look into this. That said, I'd still like to know how to get around this problem if I encounter it in the future.

Comment: Wikipedia is using non-breaking spaces and thin spaces, hardly any null characters. And even then, `\s` should match those. Please show us what exactly you tried doing with that regex. You definitely should not use `enocde/decodeURI…`

Comment: You should read [Please do not use a web crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Why_not_just_retrieve_data_from_wikipedia.org_at_runtime.3F) on the wikipedia site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks surrounding the first argument of `replace`. This is because you are using a regular expression ( `/g` )for the replace function, which does not need to be wrapped in quotation marks.

```
function replaceBadSpaces(string) {
    return decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(string).replace(/%C2%A0/g, "%20"));
}
```

Comment: One should just use `replace(/\u00a0/g, ' ')`, there no need to use any URI encoding.